# Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022でショートカットiconの設定変更ができない

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio Professional 2022を使用
Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022の拡張機能使用しています。

setupを作成し、ApplicationFolderにプロジェクトの出力と32×32(32bit)のiconを挿入。
その後User'sDesktopフォルダにプロジェクトのショットカットを作成、このショートカットのプロパティからiconを設定を実行しようとしたところ、プルダウンに”None”や”Browse...”などの選択項目が無くiconが設定できません。

VS2017、VS2019では同じ作業で問題なくiconの設定ができます。
(VS2017,2019はMicrosoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022ではなくMicrosoft Visual Studio Installer Projectsを使用しています。)

どなたか解決方法分かる方いらっちゃいますか？[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]